# How to implement poly line label in d3 donut pie chart?

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js

I am trying to implement D3 donut pie chart in my project which basically looks 
 like [this](http://pshivale.github.io/psd3/samples/donut_chart_multilevel.html).

The labels in this chart is fine when the number of data is 
 small but as the data increases and pie gets small the label gets overlapped 
 making it unable to read, my pie looks like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/s0deM.png).

How can I make my label 
 like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/dbuezas/9306799)?

**My code:**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="d3Dashboard.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js"></script>

  <div id="chartContainer" class="card card-body bg-light"></div>


<script type="text/javascript">
    var sampleData =[{"level":0,"name":"PROBOSCIDEA","common_name":"","children":[{"level":1,"name":"Elephantidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Elephas maximus ","common_name":"Asian Elephant","children_no":1}],"children_no":1}],"children_no":1},{"level":0,"name":"SCANDENTIA","common_name":"","children":[{"level":1,"name":"Tupaiidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Tupaia belangeri ","common_name":"Northern Treeshrew","children_no":1}],"children_no":1}],"children_no":1},{"level":0,"name":"PRIMATES","common_name":"","children":[{"level":1,"name":"Cercopithecidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Macaca assamensis ","common_name":"Assam Macaque","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Macaca  mulatta","common_name":"Rhesus Macaque","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Semnopithecus entellus ","common_name":"Northern Plains Gray Langur","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Semnopithecus hector ","common_name":"Tarai Gray Langur","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Semnopithecus  schistaceus","common_name":"Nepal Gray Langur","children_no":1}],"children_no":5}],"children_no":1},{"level":0,"name":"RODENTIA","common_name":"","children":[{"level":1,"name":"Sciuridae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Ratufa bicolor ","common_name":"Black Giant Squirrel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Belomys pearsonii","common_name":"Hairy-footed Flying Squirrel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Eupetaurus cinereus ","common_name":"Woolly Flying Squirrel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Hylopetes alboniger ","common_name":"Particoloured Flying Squirrel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Petaurista elegans ","common_name":"Spotted Giant Flying Squirrel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Petaurista magnificus  ","common_name":"Hodgson's Giant Flying Squirrel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Petaurista nobilis ","common_name":"Bhutan Giant Flying Squirrel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Petaurista petaurista ","common_name":"Red Giant Flying Squirrel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Callosciurus erythraeus ","common_name":"Pallas?s Squirrel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Callosciurus pygerythrus ","common_name":"Irrawaddy Squirrel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Dremomys  lokriah","common_name":"Orange-bellied Himalayan Squirrel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Funambulus pennantii ","common_name":"Northern Palm Squirrel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Tamiops macclellandii ","common_name":"Himalayan Striped Squirrel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Marmota himalayana ","common_name":"Himalayan Marmot","children_no":1}],"children_no":14},{"level":1,"name":"Spalacidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Cannomys badius ","common_name":"Lesser Bamboo Rat","children_no":1}],"children_no":1},{"level":1,"name":"Cricetidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Alticola roylei ","common_name":"Royle's Mountain Vole","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Neodon  sikimensis","common_name":"Sikkim Mountain Vole","children_no":1}],"children_no":2},{"level":1,"name":"Muridae","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Tatera  indica","common_name":"Indian Gerbil","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Bandicota bengalensis","common_name":"Lesser Bandicoot-rat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Bandicota indica ","common_name":"Greater Bandicoot-rat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Dacnomys millardi","common_name":"Millard?s Dacnomys","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Golunda ellioti  ","common_name":"Indian Bush Rat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Leopoldamys  edwardsi","common_name":"Edward?s Leopoldamys","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Mus booduga ","common_name":"Little Indian Field Mouse","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Mus musculus","common_name":"House Mouse","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Mus  pahari","common_name":"Indochinese Shrew-like Mouse","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Niviventer eha ","common_name":"Smoke-bellied Niviventer","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Niviventer  fulvescens","common_name":"Indomalayan Niviventer","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Niviventer niviventer ","common_name":"Himalayan Niviventer","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rattus andamanensis  ","common_name":"Indochinese Forest Rat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rattus nitidus ","common_name":"White-footed Indochinese Rat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rattus  pyctoris","common_name":"Himalayan Rat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rattus   rattus","common_name":"Roof Rat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rattus  tanezumi","common_name":"Oriental House Rat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Vandeleuria  oleracea","common_name":"Indomalayan Vandeleuria","children_no":1}],"children_no":18},{"level":1,"name":"Hystricidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Hystrix brachyura ","common_name":"Malayan Porcupine","children_no":1}],"children_no":1}],"children_no":5},{"level":0,"name":"LAGOMORPHA","common_name":"","children":[{"level":1,"name":"Ochotonidae","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Ochotona curzoniae ","common_name":"Plateau Pika","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Ochotona forresti ","common_name":"Forrest's Pika","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Ochotona macrotis ","common_name":"Large-eared Pika","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Ochotona roylei ","common_name":"Royle's Pika","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Ochotona  thibetana","common_name":"Moupin Pika","children_no":1}],"children_no":5},{"level":1,"name":"Leporidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Caprolagus  hispidus","common_name":"Hispid Hare","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Lepus  nigricollis","common_name":"Indian Hare","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Lepus oiostolus","common_name":"Wolly Hare ","children_no":1}],"children_no":3}],"children_no":2},{"level":0,"name":"SORICOMORPHA","common_name":"","children":[{"level":1,"name":"Soricidae","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Crocidura  attenuata","common_name":"Asian Gray Shrew","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Suncus  etruscus","common_name":"Etruscan Shrew","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Suncus  murinus","common_name":"Asian Musk Shrew","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Chimarrogale  himalayica","common_name":"Himalayan Water Shrew","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Episoriculus  caudatus","common_name":"Hodgson's Brown-toothed Shrew","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Episoriculus  leucops","common_name":"Long-tailed Brown-toothed Shrew","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Episoriculus  macrurus","common_name":"Long-tailed Mountain Shrew","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Nectogale  elegans","common_name":"Elegant Water Shrew","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Soriculus  nigrescens","common_name":"Himalayan Shrew","children_no":1}],"children_no":9},{"level":1,"name":"Talpidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Euroscaptor micrura  ","common_name":"Himalayan Mole","children_no":1}],"children_no":1}],"children_no":2},{"level":0,"name":"CHIROPTERA","common_name":"","children":[{"level":1,"name":"Pteropodidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Cynopterus sphinx ","common_name":"Greater Short-nosed Fruit Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Eonycteris  spelaea","common_name":"Lesser Dawn Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Megaerops niphanae ","common_name":"Ratanaworabhan?s Fruit Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Macroglossus  sobrinus","common_name":"Greater Long-nosed Fruit Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Pteropus  giganteus","common_name":"Indian Flying Fox","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rousettus  leschenaultii","common_name":"Leschenault's Rousette","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Sphaerias  blanfordi","common_name":"Blanford's Fruit Bat","children_no":1}],"children_no":7},{"level":1,"name":"Rhinolophidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Rhinolophus  affinis","common_name":"Intemediate Horseshoe Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rhinolophus ferrumequinum ","common_name":"Greater Horseshoe Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rhinolophus  lepidus","common_name":"Blyth?s Horseshoe Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rhinolophus luctus ","common_name":"Woolly Horseshoe Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rhinolophus  macrotis","common_name":"Big-eared Horseshoe Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rhinolophus  pearsonii","common_name":"Pearson?s Horseshoe Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rhinolophus  pusillus","common_name":"Least Horseshoe Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rhinolophus  rouxii","common_name":"Rufous Horseshoe Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rhinolophus  sinicus","common_name":"Chinese Rufous Horseshoe Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rhinolophus  trifoliatus","common_name":"Trefoil Horseshoe Bat","children_no":1}],"children_no":10},{"level":1,"name":"Hipposideridae","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Coelops  frithii","common_name":"East Asian Tailless Leaf-nosed Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Hipposideros  armiger","common_name":"Great Leaf-nosed Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Hipposideros  cineraceus","common_name":"Ashy Leaf-nosed Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Hipposideros  lankadiva","common_name":"Kelaart?s Leaf-nosedBat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Hipposideros  pomona","common_name":"Pomona Leaf-nosed Bat","children_no":1}],"children_no":5},{"level":1,"name":"Megadermatidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Megaderma  lyra","common_name":"Greater False Vampire Bat","children_no":1}],"children_no":1},{"level":1,"name":"Emballonuridae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Taphozous  longimanus","common_name":"Long-winged Tomb Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Taphozous nudiventris ","common_name":"Naked-rumped Tomb Bat","children_no":1}],"children_no":2},{"level":1,"name":"Molossidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Tadarida  teniotis","common_name":"European Free-tailed Bat","children_no":1}],"children_no":1},{"level":1,"name":"Vespertilionidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Arielulus circumdatus","common_name":"Bronze Sprite","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Eptesicus  serotinus","common_name":"Common Serotine","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Eptesicus  tatei","common_name":"Sombre Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Scotomanes  ornatus","common_name":"Harlequin Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Scotophilus  kuhlii","common_name":"Lesser Asiatic Yellow Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Nyctalus   noctula","common_name":"Noctule","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Pipistrellus  cadornae","common_name":"Cadorna's Pipistrelle","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Pipistrellus coromandra ","common_name":"Indian Pipistrelle","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Pipistrellus javanicus ","common_name":"Javan Pipistrelle","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Pipistrellus  tenuis","common_name":"Least Pipistrelle","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Barbastella  leucomelas","common_name":"Eastern Barbastelle","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Plecotus  auritus","common_name":"Brown Long-eared Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Falsistrellus  affinis","common_name":"Chocolate Pipistrelle","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Philetor  brachypterus","common_name":"Rohu?s Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Tylonycteris  pachypus","common_name":"Lesser Bamboo Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Myotis  annectans","common_name":"Hairy-faced Myotis","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Myotis formosus","common_name":"Hodgson?s Myotis","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Myotis  muricola","common_name":"Nepalese Whiskered Myotis","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Myotis nipalensis","common_name":"Nepal Myotis","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Myotis  sicarius","common_name":"Mandelli?s Mouse-eared Myotis","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Myotis  siligorensis","common_name":"Himalayan Whiskered Myotis","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Harpiocephalus  harpia","common_name":"Lesser Hairy-winged Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Harpiocephalus  mordax","common_name":"Greater Hairy-winged Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Murina  aurata","common_name":"Little Tube-nosed Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Murina  cyclotis","common_name":"Round-eared Tube-nosed Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Murina  huttoni","common_name":"Hutton?s Tube-nosed Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Murina  leucogaster","common_name":"Greater Tube-nosed Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Murina  tubinaris","common_name":"Scully?s Tube-nosed Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Kerivoula  hardwickii","common_name":"Hardwicke?s Woolly Bat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Kerivoula  picta","common_name":"Painted Woolly Bat","children_no":1}],"children_no":30}],"children_no":7},{"level":0,"name":"PHOLIDOTA","common_name":"","children":[{"level":1,"name":"Manidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Manis  crassicaudata","common_name":"Indian Pangolin","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Manis  pentadactyla","common_name":"Chinese Pangolin","children_no":1}],"children_no":2}],"children_no":1},{"level":0,"name":"CARNIVORA","common_name":"","children":[{"level":1,"name":"Felidae","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Catopuma  temminckii","common_name":"Asiatic Golden Cat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Felis  chaus","common_name":"Jungle Cat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Lynx  lynx","common_name":"Eurasian Lynx","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Pardofelis  marmorata","common_name":"Marbled Cat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Prionailurus  bengalensis","common_name":"Leopard Cat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Prionailurus  viverrinus","common_name":"Fishing Cat","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Neofelis  nebulosa","common_name":"Clouded Leopard","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Panthera  uncia","common_name":"Snow Leopard","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Panthera  pardus","common_name":"Leopard","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Panthera  tigris","common_name":"Tiger","children_no":1}],"children_no":10},{"level":1,"name":"Viverridae","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Arctictis  binturong","common_name":"Binturong","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Paguma larvata","common_name":"Masked Palm Civet","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Paradoxurus  hermaphroditus","common_name":"Asian Palm Civet","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Viverra  zibetha","common_name":"Large Indian Civet","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Viverricula indica","common_name":"Small Indian Civet","children_no":1}],"children_no":5},{"level":1,"name":"Prionodontinae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Prionodon pardicolor ","common_name":"Spotted Linsang","children_no":1}],"children_no":1},{"level":1,"name":"Herpestidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Herpestes auropunctatus?","common_name":"Small Indian Mongoose","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Herpestes edwardsii","common_name":"Grey Mongoose","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Herpestes  urva","common_name":"Crab-eating Mongoose","children_no":1}],"children_no":3},{"level":1,"name":"Canidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Canis  aureus","common_name":"Golden Jackal","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Canis lupus?","common_name":"Grey Wolf","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Cuon  alpinus","common_name":"Dhole","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Vulpes  bengalensis","common_name":"Bengal Fox","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Vulpes  ferrilata","common_name":"Tibetan Sand Fox","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Vulpes  vulpes","common_name":"Red Fox","children_no":1}],"children_no":6},{"level":1,"name":"Ursidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Melursus  ursinus","common_name":"Sloth Bear","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Ursus  arctos","common_name":"Brown Bear","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Ursus  thibetanus","common_name":"Asiatic Black Bear","children_no":1}],"children_no":3},{"level":1,"name":"Mustelidae","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Aonyx  cinereus","common_name":"Oriental small-clawed Otter","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Lutra  lutra","common_name":"Eurasian Otter","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Lutrogale perspicillata ","common_name":"Smooth-coated Otter","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Arctonyx collaris ","common_name":"Hog-badger","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Martes  flavigula","common_name":"Yellow-throated Marten","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Martes foina ","common_name":"Beech Marten","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Melogale personata ","common_name":"Burmese Ferret Badger","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Mustela altaica ","common_name":"Mountain Weasel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Mustela kathiah ","common_name":"Yellow-bellied Weasel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Mustela  sibirica","common_name":"Siberian Weasel","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Mustela  strigidorsa","common_name":"Black-striped Weasel","children_no":1}],"children_no":11},{"level":1,"name":"Ailuridae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Ailurus  fulgens","common_name":"Red Panda","children_no":1}],"children_no":1}],"children_no":8},{"level":0,"name":"PERISSODACTYLA","common_name":"","children":[{"level":1,"name":"Equidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Equus  kiang","common_name":"Kiang","children_no":1}],"children_no":1}],"children_no":1},{"level":0,"name":"ARTIODACTYLA","common_name":"","children":[{"level":1,"name":"Suidae","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Porcula  salvania","common_name":"Pygmy Hog","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Sus  scrofa","common_name":"Wild Boar","children_no":1}],"children_no":2},{"level":1,"name":"Moschidae","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Moschus  chrysogaster","common_name":"Alpine Musk Deer","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Moschus  fuscus","common_name":"Black Musk Deer","children_no":1}],"children_no":2},{"level":1,"name":"Cervidae ","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Axis  axis","common_name":"Chital","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Muntiacus  muntjak","common_name":"Indian Muntjac","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Rusa  unicolor","common_name":"Sambar","children_no":1}],"children_no":3},{"level":1,"name":"Bovidae","common_name":"","children":[{"level":2,"name":"Procapra  picticaudata","common_name":"Tibetan Gazelle","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Bos  gaurus","common_name":"Gaur","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Budorcas  taxicolor","common_name":"Mishmi Takin","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Capricornis  thar","common_name":"Himalayan Serow","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Hemitragus jemlahicus ","common_name":"Himalayan Tahr","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Naemorhedus  goral","common_name":"Himalayan Brown Goral","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Ovis ammon?","common_name":"Argali","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Pantholops  hodgsonii","common_name":"Chiru","children_no":1},{"level":2,"name":"Pseudois  nayaur","common_name":"Bharal","children_no":1}],"children_no":9}],"children_no":4}];

    var config = {
            containerId: "chartContainer",
            width: 800,
            height: 800,
            data: sampleData,
            label: function(d) {
                //return d.data.name + " : " + d.data.children_no;
                 return d.data.name;
            },        
            value: "children_no",
            inner: "children",
            tooltip: function(d) {
                // return "<p> "+ d.name + " "+ d.children_no +" observations.</p>";
                //return "<div><strong>" + d.name + "</strong> has <br>" + d.children_no + " child taxa.</div>";
                return "<div><strong>" + d.name + "</strong> " + d.common_name + "</div>";
            },
            // transition: "bounce",
            transitionDuration: 50,
            donutRadius: 10
        };
        var samplePie = new psd3.Pie(config);
</script>
```

Comment: the type of chart your have made is a Sunburst type (https://observablehq.com/@d3/sunburst), while that in the example you would like is a regular pie/donut chart. The data structure is very different and labeling in the way it is labelled in the pie chart may make your figure very cluttered and could cause labels to overlap. Are you sure you want to do that? Maybe better to use a tooltip?

Comment: @Coola thank you for your suggestion. Is there a way to make my labels look like the ones that are here https://observablehq.com/@d3/zoomable-sunburst.

Comment: Because you are using psd3 and not just d3js it is difficult to customize it. It will probably be easier for you to make it according to the Observable notebook itself. The idea is to rotate the labels using a transform function. In the notebook the function is called `labelTransform`, which calculates the rotation based on the relative position of the element on the chart.